# How do I save the Distressed Patient?

Tags: baldurs-gate-3

I completed combat with Malus Thorm (The Surgeon), and there's a Distressed Patient still locked into the Surgical Bed. He is still alive, but he has the condition "In Surgery" which says "Unable to move while strapped onto the operating gurney". Right clicking on the Surgical Bed says that lockpicking is impossible. Talking to him only offers the dialog "Rgrl. Gn - ungh. Ngh!"

How do I let the Distressed Patient out of the Surgical Bed and save him?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The patient can be removed from the table by using the spell Knock, which unlocks it. However, you cannot save him, as the patient immediately moves a few steps forward and then dies in a puddle of blood. The game says "Distressed patient fell to a lethal blow." Casting a spell like Sanctuary does not save him from the lethal blow. Casting Speak with Dead does not offer any more dialog options.